# Mod_Rewrite Difference between [L] and [R]

Tags: ajax, apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to rewrite any URL with "_excaped_fragment_=/some/directory" to "/some/directory?ajax=1".  The code below is working correctly but i would like to do it without the redirect.  This is a Wordpress site.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
    RewriteRule (.*) %1?ajax=1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I remove "R=301" and just leave the "L" it does not work.  I have read about [L] not stopping when from .htaccess, but i actually do not want it to stop.  I would like it to just change the URL then go through the regular Wordpress rewrite.

Any ideas?  Let me know if you need more information.

Edit:
Wanted to add an answerable question.  Why does a redirect work and no redirect not work?  Does the URL get changed as it works its way down the file or only on the last rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [L] will stop any further processing in .htaccess if the rule matched.

The way you have this written the [L] will do that, but then you add [R=301] which is a redirect.   That will cause the request to be sent back to the "top of the stack" in Apache for processing as if it was a completely new request, since you are doing a redirect.  HOWEVER, now on the 2nd time through you've got the modified URL because the rewrite was processed before doing the hand-off.

In other words [L] does the mangling, then says "OK, we are done here, drop out to normal web processing now".

[L,R=301] does the mangling, then says "we are done with THAT, now got tell whomever is next is line that we've done a redirect".

That last part of the [L,R=301] triggers a whole new set of logic to process the "hey, we just got a redirect" rules.  In your case, causing the entire rewrite sequence to be processed from the top with the mangled URL this time around.

Comment: BTW - have you tried taking of the [L] AND the [R=301] on the first rule?